# Warning: session_start(): Setting option 'auto_start' failed

Tags: php

Me aparece el siguiente error en la línea 10: **Warning: session_start(): Setting option 'auto_start' failed**

```
session_start([
    'use_only_cookies' => 1,
    'auto_start' => 1,
    'read_and_close' => true
]);
```

Que corresponde al **'auto_start' => 1,** revise la documentación de PHP y esta bien escrita la directiva.

http://php.net/manual/es/session.configuration.php

Estoy utilizando PHP 7.0.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fijate que en la tabla [Opciones de configuración de sesión](http://php.net/manual/es/session.configuration.php)

Tienes lo siguiente:

```
Nombre               | Por defecto    | Cambiable
--------------------------------------------------------
session.auto_start   | "0"            |  PHP_INI_PERDIR
```

[Si revisas el valor Cambiable](http://php.net/manual/es/configuration.changes.modes.php) (**PHP_INI_PERDIR**), veras que no se puede modificar en tiempo de ejecución:

```
Modo            | Significado
----------------------------------
PHP_INI_USER    | La entrada se puede establecer en scripts de usuario (como con ini_set()) o en el registro de Windows. Desde PHP 5.3, la entrada puede ser establecida en .user.ini
PHP_INI_PERDIR  | La entrada se puede establecer en php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf o .user.ini (desde PHP 5.3)
PHP_INI_SYSTEM  | La entrada se puede establecer en php.ini o en httpd.conf
PHP_INI_ALL     | La entrada se puede establecer en cualquier lugar
```

Por lo que esa directiva en concreto solo se puede modificar en **php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf o .user.ini**.

Igualmente no tendría ningun sentido hacer lo que pretendes, pues no tentendria sentido (en tiempo de ejecución) decirle a PHP que autoinicie sesión a la vez que inicias sesión.

Answer (score 0):

Hola para habilitar el auto_start si estas usando xampp ve al panel en configuracion y abre el php.ini, luego busca auto_start y en el parametro 0 cambialo a 1 con eso quedara activo si luego vas a subir la aplicacion a un servidor debes estar seguro q podras modificarlo directamente en el php.ini para q este habilitado por lo tanto no necesitarias en el session_start de tu arreglo incluirlo xq ya estara activo te quedaria de esta forma, yo lo solucione de esa forma.. =)

```
session_start([
'use_only_cookies' => 1,
'read_and_close' => true
```

]);