# Errores al realizar conexión con PHP y SQLSERVER utilizando IIS

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, iis, dll

Estoy algo confundido con la conexión la conexión que tengo a SQLSERVER ya que e intentado varias cosas y no se quieren agregar los drivers .dll (***extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll***, ***extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll***), o si se agregan marca otro error. Les comparto los 2 escenarios que se me están presentando.

> Caso 1 INSTALACIÓN DE PHP MANUALMENTE

Descargue PHP y descomprimí el archivo rar en dentro del disco **C:/** para posteriormente llamada al archivo ***C:\php-7.4.9\php-cgi.exe*** en el IIS, agregue los archivos .dll en la carpeta ext y los llame en el archivo php.ini, finalmente reinicio el servidor IIS. La pagina se visualiza correctamente (ANEXO 5) pero al hacer un phpinfo() no se ve que se haya agregado el archivo pdo_sqlsvr y los módulos que tienen conexión con SQLSERVER manda el siguiente error ***Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect(ANEXO 1)***.

Y en ocasiones manda este otro error (ANEXO 2), pero si refresco la pagina se quita

**ANEXO 5**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ANEXO 1**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ANEXO 2**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**phpinfo (no muestra pdo_sqlsvr).**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Caso 2 INSTALO PHP CON MICROSOFT WEB PLATFORM

Para hacer este paso primero elimine el módulo de PHP que había instalado en el IIS, después con ***MICROSOFT WEB PLATFORM*** instale el PHP y el driver para conexiones SQLSERVER sin tener que poner los .dll ya que lo puso en automático, finalmente visualice la página pero resulta que no se visualiza y manda el siguiente error ***mysqli::real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]*** (ANEXO 4).

**ANEXO 4**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**phpinfo (si muestra pdo_sqlsrv)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Conexión a SQLSERVER.

```
$db['sqlserver'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => $db_hostname_tres,
    'username' => 'sa',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => $db_name_tres,
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

La verdad es que ya realicé de todo y no logro solucionar este problema de conexión.

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Saludos y excelente inicio de semana.

Comment: No queda claro en qué escenario estás ahora. **Uno:** debes instalar los `.dll` correctos según tu versión de PHP/Sistema operativo y quizá hacer algunos cambios en  `php.ini` ,,, por varios casos que he visto la instalación de los drivers de SQL Server para PHP es confusa quizá debido a tantas versiones y demás historias. **Dos:** parece que los drivers de PDO se instalaron, pero el mensaje de error indica que tu código no es correcto, ¿qué hace ahí `mysqli_real_connect`? Si quieres conectar con PDO debes usar `new PDO(...parámetros..)`, revisa el Manual para ver cómo poner los parámetros.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano En el ejemplo menciono 2 escenarios, en cada uno de ellos me muestra diferentes errores.
En el 1ER caso no se instalan los dll pero si se visualiza la página (anexo los errores) y en el 2DO caso si se instalan utilizando MICROSOFT WEB PLATFORM, pero no se visualiza la página (anexe errores). En el framework no es necesario colocar esto “new PDO” ya que existe un archivo donde se establecen las conexiones que vas a ocupar.

Comment: Entonces creo que son dos preguntas en una. En el primer escenario tienes que buscar el modo de instalar tus `.dll` correctos y quizá hacer los cambios en el archivo `php.ini` que explique la documentación. Como ya dije, por algunas preguntas surgidas aquí, instalar los `. dll` es confuso sobre todo por la cantidad de versiones y demás, que si 32 bits, que si 64 bits, etc. Y en el segundo escenario el mensaje de error es claro, habla de un error sobre `mysqli_real_connect`, que es otra API **distinta** de PDO, por lo que no creo que tu framework  te esté resolviendo el problema...

Comment: ... parecería que intenta conectar con `mysqli`, pero deberías usar `new PDO()` sí o sí. PDO es una clase y se conecta creando una instancia de la misma, no hay otro modo. El [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php) es claro en ese punto, y [la doc de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/example-application-pdo-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver15) también, por tanto, `mysqli` no pinta nada ahí.

Comment: @A.Cedano Te anexo mi conexion, es la misma conexion que utilizo en local y así es como se declaran las conexiones con CodeIgniter.

Comment: No uso Codeigniter, pero me parece que si quieres conectar con PDO, esto: `'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',` deberías cambiarlo por esto: `'dbdriver' => 'pdo',`  y el `dsn` no debería estar en blanco.

Comment: Dudo que se conecte ya que en primer lugar en el 1ER caso no se a agregado el driver pd_sqlsvr y eso se puede checar en el phpinfo()

Comment: Revisa lo que dice [la Doc de Codeigniter](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html) al respecto: *Some database drivers (such as PDO, PostgreSQL, Oracle, ODBC) might require a full DSN string to be provided. If that is the case, you should use the ‘DSN’ configuration setting, as if you’re using the driver’s underlying native PHP extension...* y mira el ejemplo que ponen sobre PDO con respecto al DSN.

Comment: Ya coloque pdo en vez de sqlsvr y manda este error "Invalid or non-existent PDO subdriver" y sigue sin mostrar el driver en phpinfo

Comment: Es muy probable que los drivers no estén bien instalados en ninguno de los casos. Recomiendo que leas las indicaciones específicas para tu entorno (Versión de Windows, Versión de PHP, etc)  y sigas paso a paso las instrucciones que te da Microsoft para la instalación. Debes cuidar de descargar/instalar los archivos exactos para tu configuración.

Comment: Lo solucione con este post https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96223/warning-session-start-setting-option-auto-start-failed